# how to delete a image file from IBM content manager for ISeries using an external application?

Tags: ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator, db2-content-manager

I am doing maintenance to an old application written in vb that reads images files from and IFS (Integrated File System) folder.

I need to add a feature where users can delete images from this folder; however, I am getting the following error:

[image: File Access Denied]

Content Manager is ISERIES db2 database. I am even able to delete the record from the database, but concerning this image, how can I delete this? Any suggestions? I am new in AS400. I am still doing research about it but no success.

Regards,

Comment: Can you show the actual path to the document on the server? Especially the top-level directory (file system node) should be shown. Different file systems can have some particular restrictions.

Comment: this is the path for this document:  \\qs102mz5m\Root\VIFLDR28\SUBDIREC.001

Comment: That looks like a path from the client (e.g., Windows) rather than the path on the server. As such, it probably indicates the 'share' definition and may obscure the actual path on the server. Please show the path on the server.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying right now to get that server path; I am not that familiar with ISERIES.

Comment: Would the path be like /CWES007B/SUBDIREC.001/00007A54.001?

Comment: For what i am seeing in Iseries Nav, the folder path is /WaImages/VIFLDR28/SUBDIREC.001/*

Comment: That looks much more likely. I needed to see the top-level node to be sure of the file system. If the path started with /QDLS/* or perhaps something similar, there could be some tricky alternatives. Now we can be a little more certain. (And now I need to refamiliarize myself with the question.)

Comment: I was reading a file from IBM; there is this library : "EKDVIAPI.H" am i in the right track?

Comment: I assume that that is a source member made available to customers with Content Manager (DB2CM). It would likely contain sample C prototypes and definitions to use for your own programming that interacts with DB2CM objects. If any API exposes appropriate `delete` functions, it should be helpful. It's not clear yet if needed. Can you explain what you're actually trying to create? Does DB2CM not expose a `delete` function for users? Is this just one particular object that won't delete? Does the error show up in DB2CM or is it when any delete is attempted, e.g., via Windows Explorer?

Comment: The application that i am trying to modify, reads the file from the windows server path. So, my first attempt was to delete it the same way(getting the error previously shown). However, the file are IFS (Integrated File System) with read-only property. Therefore, I am assuming that the only way I have is to get connected to the ISeries Content Manager and delete this file and, that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Read-only shouldn't make any difference; such objects can still be deleted. The problem would be in permissions/authorities for the user ID against the object, or maybe in DB2CM where it tries to execute your request and rejects it due to configuration. I would first check the system audit journal, QAUDJRN, for any related entries for the time to `delete` is requested. That should log permissions problems. (Note that when you add clarifying detail, it's helpful to edit your original question to add the new details. Comments may be deleted later.)

Comment: Show the code your using to delete the IFS files.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your user profile has read only rights. Check with ls -la
If you aren't the owner, or don't have rights, you won't be able to delete the file.
At this point, the SETGID bit can be a solution. Try to discuss this issue with your admin.